XPATH text() Function & Similar Functions: Where's A Reference?
I'm trying to get better at using XPATH – specifically in Javascript via document.evaluate()
Normally, when learning new aspects of Javascript, I do my research on the MDN docs, as they tend to be super-comprehensive and well-written
However, when I look at their XPath Functions Reference, text() does not appear
I'm guessing that this has to do with it not being part of the general XPath standard, but added in for specific HTML-related browser implementations?  It seems to work the same in Chrome, Firefox, and beyond, though... so I can't imagine it not being standardized in some respect
Where can I find an XPath reference that will document this function, and other similar ones added into standard Javascript browser implementations?
I tried googling for things like "XPath text() function reference," and while I found many tutorials talking about how to use them, I can still find no reference documentation

Look at 2.3 Node Tests in the official xpath doc. So it's not a xpath function but a node test.

i.e see: http://www.utools.nl/downloads/XPathReference.pdf

Go to the official W3C specifications for the version of XPath you are using: they are quite readable. The XPath 1.0 version is perhaps a little terse, the later versions perhaps a little verbose, but you should find they contain what you need.
The XPath 1.0 version is at https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/
Alternatively (shameless plug) there are always books, such as my own.
The problem with online reference sources such as MDN is that they're good for reference, but they don't teach you the concepts. If you don't already know that text() is a node test rather than a function, they aren't going to help you much.
Also, a good book won't just tell you what a construct like text() does, it will also give you lots of advice and guidance on when to use it. The web is absolutely full of examples of text() being used really badly, and people who learn mainly by copying examples from the web compound the problem.
